# showing equivalence relation proof

Tags: real-analysis

Let R be a relation on X that satisfies:

(a) For all a in X, (a,a) in R, and 
(b) For a,b,c in x, if (a,b), (b,c) in Rm then (c,a) in R.

I need to show that R is an equivalence relation.

I know that an equivelence relation is defined by:
a = a (reflexive property),
a = b then b = a (symmetric property), and
a = b and b = c then a = c (transitive property).

but im not sure how i can show this here.

Comment: If $(a,b)$ is in R, the we'll always have $(b,b)$ in R

Answer (score 1):

As $(a,a)$ in $R$ for all $a$ we have $R$ is reflexive.

Let's put a pin in symmetric.

We have a sort of backwards transitive in that $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ in $R$ imply $(c,a)$ in $R$ but if we have symmetry we would have $(c,a) $ in $R$ implies $(a,c)$ in $R$.

So all we have to do is show $R$ is symmetric.

I'll leave that to you but give you the hint that if $(a,b)$ is in $R$ we know that $(a,a)$ as well as $(b,b)$ are in $R$.  Do something with those and the weird backwards transitivity.

=======

Full answer:

Reflexive:  For all $a\in X$, $(a,a)\in R$.

Pf: We were given that.

Symmetric: If $(a,b)\in R$ then $(b,a)\in R$.

If we have $(a,b) \in R$, then because $R$ is symmetric we have $(b,b)\in R$ as well.  So by our strange condition [if $(a,b),(b,c)\in R$ then $(c,a)\in R$] we have $(a,b),(b,b)\in R$ so we have $(b,a) \in R$.  So that's that.

Transitivity:  If $(a,b),(b,c) \in R$ then $(a,c)\in R$.

Pf:  If $(a,b),(b,c) \in R$ our strange condition tells us $(c,a)\in R$. And as $R$ is symmetric $(a,c)\in R$.

Comment: doesn't that last statement directly imply that (b,a) is in R

Comment: or do i need to show it for (a,c)

Comment: Maybe my hint was too much.  But yes if $(a,b)\in R$, and we know $(b,b)\in R$ so $(a,b),(b,b)\in R$ and by the weird condition $(b,a)\in R$.  So if $(a,b)\in R$ then $(b,a) \in R$ and thus symmetry holds.